# Can I chown /etc/hosts so my user owns it so I can edit it without sudo?

Tags: macos, text-editors, hosts, ownership

It's a bit inconvenient to have to `sudo emacs /etc/hosts` whenever I want to make a change to my hosts file, especially since I don't use a Terminal-based editor primarily. Could I change the ownership of my hosts file so that my user is the owner and thus the file could be edited in any text editor I open? Would that cause any problems for OS X?

Comment: What editor are you using instead?

Comment: There are text editors such as TextWrangler that can automatically authenticate and edit the file with root privileges.

Comment: Have you tried other terminal-based text editors? As well as `emacs`, Mac OS X should have `vim` (cue holy war) `ed` (of course) and `nano` installed already, and many more can be acquired. Personally I find `emacs` far too heavyweight for small changes to configuration files, and thus prefer `nano`.

Comment: I'm using ActiveState Komodo Edit. I wish it did what TextWrangler and Coda did with prompting for sudo privileges. I used to use `nano` to edit my hosts file, but recently have been using `emacs`. However, it's not the primary editor I use, so I'd rather have some consistency and just use Komodo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can<sup>1</sup>. No, you definitely should not. It won't break your OS X by itself, but...

...having system configuration files restricted from writing by non-admins is precisely how Unix systems have resisted most malware. On the other hand, in older versions of Windows you could often find popular sites redirected to a password-stealing site or a completely nonexistent server.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're going to do it, better just add yourself to the [access list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) instead of changing ownership: `sudo chmod +a "$USER allow read,write" /etc/hosts`

Comment: Only that won't work with almost all non terminal editors, as they perform atomic saves and need to write files to /etc.

Comment: @DanielBeck: And neither will `chown`, unless the user has +write permission on the whole `/etc`. At which point I just let the user continue with breaking their machine by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you're editing the hosts file that frequently, why not just create an alias? Add something like `alias changehosts="sudo emacs /etc/hosts` to your login profile file, and it will be even shorter to type. You can even add a NOPASSWD directive in sudoers so you wont have to type your password (either ever, or specifically to `emacs /etc/hosts`). Fundamental security doesn't really have to come at the expense of productivity.